# How to handle a fluent interface where each step can be a terminal operation?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

I am building a fluent API that roughly works like this (assuming a class `Person` with a getter `getId` exists that returns a `Long`):

```
String result = context.map(Person::getId)
     .pipe(Object::toString)
     .pipe(String::toUpperCase)
     .end(Function.identity())
```

As you can see only the `.end`-function acts a terminal operator. This clutters the overall usage of said API as I often have to end in a `.end(Function.identity())`-call even though the preceding `.pipe`-call already has the right type.

Is there any way to make a fluent-API that enables a part of it to be both a terminal operator and a 'bridge-operator'? I just dont want to clutter the API with specialized  `pipe`-variants like `pipeTo` (a pipe that only accepts a `Function<CurrentType, ExpectedType>` and internally calls `.end`)that emulate said behaviour as it forces the user to think about a very specific part of the API that seems unnecessary to me.

EDIT:
A simplified context-implementation as requested:

```
class Context<InType, CurrentType, TargetType> {
    private final Function<InType, CurrentType> getter;

    public Context(Function<InType, CurrentType> getter) {
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public <IntermediateType> Context<InType, IntermediateType, TargetType>
    pipe(Function<CurrentType, IntermediateType> mapper) {

        return new Context<>(getter.andThen(mapper));
    }

    public Function<InType, TargetType> end(Function<CurrentType, TargetType> mapper) {
        return getter.andThen(mapper);
    }
}

//usage
Function<Person, String> mapper = new Context<Person, Long, String>(Person::getId)
    .pipe(Object::toString)
    .pipe(String::toUpperCase)
    .end(Function.identity());

mapper.apply(new Person(...))
```

Comment: All I can think of is *why not `end()` (even as an overload)?* You probably need to share more info or just post the class of `context`. Not all fluent APIs are the same.

Comment: Will edit the question with a simplified context-class, thanks. Just `end()` doesnt work as you will see when I have edited my question. Thanks !

Comment: I have edited my question and as you can see I have no way (that I know of) to express an `end()` function that only works when CurrentType == TargetType. And as I have stated: `pipe` sometimes is a terminal and other times a 'bridge'-operator

Comment: I have added a link to the original post that links to the class I am having issues with

Comment: I have deleted the previously accepted answer from myself, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56108780/4934324) as to why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I had was that any `pipe` step could be a terminal operation. As outlined in the discussions below each answer and the main post: using a function with the same name twice and one being a terminal operation just is not possible in java.

I banged my head against this problem and tried multiple approaches each of which did not work. Thats when I realized what I am doing is essentially the same as Javas `Stream`-API: you have an origin (source), do some fancy stuff (pipe) and then end (collect). If we apply the same scheme to my question there is no need for `pipe` to be a terminal operation, we just need another operation (e.g. `end`) which serves as the end point. As I had some extended requirements on when end is possible (the current type must match another type) I implemented `end` by only allowing a context specific funtion for which there is only one sane implementation available (hard to explain). Here is an example of the current implementation (`pipe` has since been renamed to `map` and `end` to `to`):

```
Mapper<Person, PersonDTO> mapper = Datus.forTypes(Person.class, PersonDTO.class).immutable(PersonDTO::new)
    .from(Person::getFirstName).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
    .from(Person::getLastName)
        .given(Objects::nonNull, ln -> ln.toUpperCase()).orElse("fallback")
        .to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
    .build();
```

As you can see `.to` acts as the terminal operator and `ConstructorParameter::bind` would complain about a type mismatch if the current type would not match the expected type.

See [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/07e3a19103af03cabd19c752ac10e2480ec9fa82/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/ConstructorParameterBinding.java) for the `to` part, [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/07e3a19103af03cabd19c752ac10e2480ec9fa82/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/ConstructorBuilder1.java) for an implementation of `ConstructorParameter` and [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/07e3a19103af03cabd19c752ac10e2480ec9fa82/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/ConstructorParameter.java) how it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, I'd overload `end()` and just get rid of the last function composition:

```
public Function<InType, CurrentType> end() {
    return this.getter;
}
```

And thinking further, I think the third type parameter for the `Context` class can be eliminated as the intermediate type is only needed at method level. Check this:

```
class OtherContext<I, O> {

    private final Function<I, O> getter;

    public OtherContext(Function<I, O> getter) {
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public <T> OtherContext<I, T> pipe(Function<O, T> mapper) {

        return new OtherContext<I, T>(getter.andThen(mapper));
    }

    public <T> Function<I, T> end(Function<O, T> mapper) {
        return getter.andThen(mapper);
    }

    public Function<I, O> end() {
        return getter;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right! This ones on me: in the complete `Context` class I don't just return the  getter but use another function of type `Function<Function<InType,TargetType>, NextStepType>` which cannot make use of this approach. I think I can't reduce my real `Context`-class in a way that won`t result in a gigantic piece of code with a lengthy explanation in the question, but thanks for your answer anyway !

Comment: I am thinking about how I can present my issue in a small example as the full context of the `Context` class is too wide. You are in for a ride buddy and I am in for some thinking :) (note: its not that I cannot post the original code, but there is just too much to explain as it is)

Comment: Its getting late around here, will check in again tomorrow

Comment: I decided to complete the library this issue is connected to first without adressing this issue, will link to the github repository once I am done (in the next days)

Comment: As promised, heres my library: https://github.com/roookeee/datus - the class I was talking about is located here https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/master/src/main/java/datus/datamapper/immutable/ImmutableConstructionStep.java

Answer (score 1):

You can't define methods in Java with the same name and different return types.  Your methods are probably returning something like `Wrapped<T>` and you want to return `T` instead.  In general what I would probably recommend is to have something like `*andEnd(...)` for each of your methods. So `pipeAndEnd(...)` would do the pipe and then end with the terminal operation.  This will probably get tedious to do so you might want to look into some code generation if you have a lot of methods.

​

On a different note, it seems like you are implementing your own version of the Stream API.  Unless you're doing this is for educational purposes, it's almost always better to use existing and well-tested / documented code (especially code part of standard jdk) than to re-implement your own version of the same thing.

Comment: Good advice on the note about reimplementing parts of the std-lib (like Stream), it's not what I am doing though