# What are the possibilities to design an API that needs overloads depending on a generic type?

Tags: java, functional-programming, api-design

In a given class `Example<A>` I need the following two functions to be available:

`void doSomething(Supplier<A>)`

`<B> void doSomething(Supplier<B>)`

What are the possibilities to achieve this? I know the following approaches:

1. give the functions different names
2. use a wrapper-type for the second-definition `WrapperType.of(Supplier<B>)`
3. use a function that converts `Example<A>` to `Example<B>`

Are there any other approaches?

I dislike 1) as it clutters my API. 2) is really verbose as I have to call said function often and static imports are very unusual outside of testing code. 3) is very explicit about the internal problem which I don't want the user to 'care' about

Comment: Care to share why this question is getting downvoted ? I would like to improve my problem description

Comment: I see, but I am looking for other approaches to have a broader solution set to decide upon. If there aren't any other thats fine for me too though. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: There is a 4th option, make an interface that implements Supplier<X>... So you can have StringSupplier, a ByteSupplier, etc... other than that though, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I will get ambigous an method call then because a lamda `() -> "Hello"` is both a `Supplier<String>` and a `StringSupplier` :(

Comment: @john16384: Your comment made me think from another angle I hadn't thought about yet. I am so thankful for your comment. Thanks, thanks, thanks :) Have a great day

Comment: There is no sense in a declaration like `<B> void doSomething(Supplier<B>)` Since `B` can be any type the caller wants, there is no difference to `void doSomething(Supplier<?>)` Since this *does* overlap with `void doSomething(Supplier<A>)`, as `B` can be `A`, the method should either, do the same, in which case it is obsolete, or it should have a different name, expressing the different operation.

Comment: You are right, my question is missing bounds on `B` but it would still be impossible to express in Java (with the same name)

Answer (score 2):

I have found another way by specifying an extension of `Function<A,B>` as follows:

```
class SpecificFunction<A,B> extends Function<A,B> {}
```

Multiple overloads on `Function<A,B>` and `SpecificFunction<A,C>` can be defined then which would be impossible without an additional class because of type erasure. This works because the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) explicitly enforces that the java compiler has to bind a function call to the most specific function it can find. One part in the defnition of how to find the most specific function is as follows: if two functions `m(a)` and `n(b)` exists `m(a)` is more specific than `n(b)` if `b` is not a subtype of `a`, which holds for our `SpecificFunction<A,B>`.

Comment: Nice, I'll remember that :)

Comment: A bit more information: actually don't use this as every non-explicitly typed lambda is always resolved to the `SpecificFunction` overload even if the type-parameter cannot match. This is because the java language specification explicitly excluded the usage of any generic type information when resolving which overload to take for such lamdas. As this only works with explicitly typed lambdas or method references - don't use it.